# Azure DevOps: PATCH REST Call in Release Pipeline returns (403) Forbidden

Tags: powershell, oauth-2.0, azure-devops, authorization, azure-devops-rest-api

**Context**

I use a PowerShell Script with an Azure PowerShell task (Task version 4.* preview) to trigger the most recent release of a certain release pipeline. After retrieving the id of the last release as well as the id of the related environment via

```
GET https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrganizationName/$azureDevOpsProjectName/_apis/release/deployments?queryOrder=descending&`$top=1&definitionId=$azureDevOpsReleasePipelineId&definitionEnvironmentId=$azureDevOpsReleaseEnvironmentId&api-version=5.0
```

I want to make a PATCH REST Call to trigger the related release via

```
PATCH https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/$azureDevOpsOrganizationName/$azureDevOpsProjectName/_apis/Release/releases/$lastDeploymentId/environments/$($lastDeploymentEnvironmentId)?api-version=5.0-preview.6
```

with the following body

```
$triggerMostRecentReleaseBody = @{
    comment = 'some comment'
    status = 2
    scheduledDeploymentTime = $null
}
$triggerMostRecentReleaseBodyJSON = $triggerMostRecentReleaseBody | ConvertTo-Json
```

To be able to make these REST Calls I enabled the OAuth token for being available in the pipeline:

[image: oauth]

and retrieve the token via `$env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN` in the PowerShell script.

**The Issue**

The GET request works perfectly fine but when executing the PATCH Call it returns the error

> (403) Forbidden

So the question is how to enable the OAuth token to make these kind of REST Calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the permissions related to the OAuth token are not sufficient by default to make the PATCH Call.

To grant the necessary permissions add the **Project Collection Build Service (xxx)** user to the **Project Administrators** group:

[image: add user]